# How do I create long table from a wide table using union in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

I have a wide PostgreSQL table that I need to change to long form using a union query. The table is like:

| visit_date | outfalls_free | outfall_obstruction_comment | outfall_obstruction_remedy | lagoon_liner | lagoon_liner_comment | lagoon_liner_remedy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/1/2022 | Pass | ok | not | needed | Pass | ok |
| 9/30/2022 | Pass | ok | not needed | NA | Repaired berm does not seem to be holding up | patch |
| 10/5/2022 | Pass | ok | not needed | Fail | Two areas of damage | patch |
| 10/14/2022 | Pass | ok | not needed | Fail NE | lagoon torn | patch |
| 10/25/2022 | Pass | ok | not needed | NA | No new breaks observed | not needed |
| 11/11/2022 | Pass | ok | not needed | Pass | ok | not needed |
| 10/19/2022 | Pass | ok | not needed | Pass | ok | not needed |
| 11/14/2022 | Pass | ok | not needed | Pass | ok | not needed |
| 11/20/2022 | Pass | ok | not needed | Pass | ok | not needed |
| 11/28/2022 | Pass | ok | not needed | Pass | ok | not needed |
| 12/15/2022 | Pass | ok | not needed | Pass | ok | not needed |

I would like to create a union query to create the table below from the one above.

| category | Date | Type | Status | Comment | Remedy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| outfall | 9/1/2022 | obstruction | Pass | ok | not needed |
| lagoon | 9/1/2022 | liner | Pass | ok | not needed |
| outfall | 9/30/2022 | obstruction | Pass | ok | not needed |
| lagoon | 9/30/2022 | liner | NA | Repaired berm does not seem to be holding up | patch |
| outfall | 10/5/2022 | obstruction | Pass | ok | not needed |
| lagoon | 10/5/2022 | liner | Fail | Two areas of damage | patch |
| outfall | 10/14/2022 | obstruction | Pass | ok | not needed |
| lagoon | 10/14/2022 | liner | Fail | NE lagoon torn | patch |
| outfall | 10/25/2022 | obstruction | Pass | ok | not needed |
| lagoon | 10/25/2022 | liner | NA | No new breaks observed | not needed |
| outfall | 11/11/2022 | obstruction | Pass | ok | not needed |
| lagoon | 11/11/2022 | liner | Pass | ok | not needed |
| outfall | 10/19/2022 | obstruction | Pass | ok | not needed |
| lagoon | 10/19/2022 | liner | Pass | ok | not needed |
| outfall | 11/14/2022 | liner | Pass | ok | not needed |
| lagoon | 11/14/2022 | liner | Pass | ok | not needed |
| outfall | 11/20/2022 | liner | Pass | ok | not needed |
| lagoon | 11/20/2022 | liner | Pass | ok | not needed |
| outfall | 11/28/2022 | liner | Pass | ok | not needed |
| lagoon | 11/28/2022 | liner | Pass | ok | not needed |
| outfall | 12/15/2022 | liner | Pass | ok | not needed |
| lagoon | 12/15/2022 | liner | Pass | ok | not needed |

So far I have can get two of the columns into one (e.g. Status) by:

`select "outfalls_free" as Status from public."Weekly Inspections"`
`union all`
`select "lagoon_liner" as Status from public."Weekly Inspections";`

How do I achieve the second table? I would think that there has to be a better way than combining multiple queries like the one above. I am new SQL and PostgreSQL. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to transform columns into rows is to create an array with the columns that need to be converted and then unnest it to create rows, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int, a text, b text, c text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'a1','b1','c1'), (2,'a2','b2','c2');

SELECT id, unnest(array[a,b,c]) FROM t;

 id | unnest 
----+--------
  1 | a1
  1 | b1
  1 | c1
  2 | a2
  2 | b2
  2 | c2
(6 rows)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/u6cwCpH0)